# Connecting to a WCF Service from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services

I have a WCF Service hosted on a remote machine.  I am able to connect to it and consume the service perfectly with a WPF application.  I also want to be able to connect to the WCF Service from a different Windows Service on a different machine. I have the app.config set up the same as the WPF app, but the Windows Service won't connect to the WCF Service.  Here is the error:

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error
>   processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the
>   remote host, or an underlying network resource issue.

Here is the app.config from the Windows Service:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ServiceIP" value="127.0.0.1"/>
  </appSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="lib" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:00:10" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:00:15"
          transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8731/WCFService/" binding="netTcpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBindingEndpoint" contract="WCFService.IWCFService"
        name="NetTcpBindingEndpoint">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Any idea why I can connect fine with a WPF app, but not from a Windows Service?

**EDIT:**

Here is how I am creating the connection in the code:

```
EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://" + remoteIP + ":8731/WCFService/");
InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(this);
wcfObj = new WCFService.WCFServiceClient(context, "NetTcpBindingEndpoint", ep);
wcfObj.Subscribe();
```

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks to Huusom I was able to get it to work by changing the account that the service is run under.  Problem is I don't want to have to ask users who install the service to go messing the the service accounts.  Is there anything I can do besides this to get it to work?  Is there some kind of security I can disable?

Comment: Have you tried to set up the connection in the code to check if it is an actual connection problem and not the loading of the .config?

Comment: It could be many things.  I've encountered this error the most when not all fields of a DataContract were provided and those fields were not marked with the EmitDefaultValue = false.  If you trace your WCF communications as shown here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx, you can track it down.

Comment: Windows Services by default do not have a current working directory of the executable's location. This can cause havoc with configuration files.

Comment: Are you running the wpf app on the box that is running the wcf service? It looks like you're trying to connect to a remote system, but your endpoint address is set to localhost. The endpoint address should be the address of the remote system, not localhost. I'm guessing that it works in the wpf app because that's running on the same box as the service...

Comment: No, I am running the wpf app from a remote machine as well.  It is on the same machine as the client windows service so I know it is possible to connect to it

Comment: @chrfin - I have edited my question to show how I am connecting to the service in the code.  What else can I do to set up the connection in the code?

Comment: try to run the windows service under your own account. It might be that the account for the windows service do not have rights to open ip ports in windows.

Comment: @Huusom - Thanks.  That did actually work.  Problem is I don't want to have to asks users who install the service to go modifying the service user account.  Can I do something to remove security to allow the system account to work?

Comment: If you need more rights for your service without a user login, you can run it under the LocalSystem account.  But a warning, that account has extensive privileges.

Comment: @Josh - It is currently running under the local system account, but that is what doesn't work.

Comment: Setup an account on your machine that belongs to the administrator group and run the windows service under this user.

Answer (score 0):

To continue from the comments on the question.
You need to set namespace reservations on the ip port: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure that article is relevant.  I am not using HTTP or HTTPS, but rather net.tcp